# javascript fill array from .txt

Tags: arrays, vbscript, text-files, windows-scripting

I've got an array in a .js file, but I would like to be able to create my arrays in a .txt file **by single lines** (no commas). So an array looks like:

```
pickWords =
[
  "Hi!",
  "Welcome!",
  "Hello!"
]
```

but instead I want to pull the array from a .txt file... this is my code so far:

```
FileName = "/array1.txt"

'Open the file for input.
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

'Read from the file and display the results.

Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
    Document.Write TextLine & "<br />"
Loop
MyFile.Close
```

I guess I'm looking for input on this subject, since the web is hard to search when you use the word "text" in a search.

**NEW**
Hmmm sorry if it's not javascript I pulled it from a site that said that it was.. here under the tab JScript.. but maybe Jscript is not javascript. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7se9d4f%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Y342

ok so then the question would be ajax vs php for pulling an external array?

Comment: you need to use ajax to have access to that file

Comment: You cannot access the filesystem from JavaScript. Are you sure you want to use JavaScript? Most of your code looks like VB or something else that I don't know.

Comment: This is NOT JavaScript, definitely!

Comment: Looks like VB or Windows scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Is this javascript for the .net framework? I know this would not work in a browser situation in terms of using readLine to read a local disk file.

Here is how you can get the file as a useable array using string.split() function:

```
FileName = "/array1.txt"
'Open the file for input.
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

fileString = "";
fileArray;

'Read from the file and display the results.
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    fileString += MyFile.ReadLine
Loop
MyFile.Close

//Now you can use fileArray as an array 
//You might need to use "\r\n" instead of "\n"
fileArray = string.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said this doesn't appear to be a javascript question but:

When you are searching google and one of your key words is a common word you need to look at possible other key words. For you fso is a good one:

http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS437US437&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=array+fso+read+from+file&qscrl=1

And I got this hit that looks like what you need:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029044152/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t101700-1.shtml